# Bash Scripting - How to set the group that new files will be created with?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, permissions

I'm doing a bash shell script and I want to change the default group that new files are created as. I know you use `umask` to change the permissions. Is there something for the group?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The `newgrp` command is used to change the current group ID during a login session.

New directories created in that session will have the group ID set by the command.

[`newgrp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/newgrp.1.html)(1)

Comment: I'm a member of the group, so why is it asking me for a password?  It doesn't like my password!

Comment: also, if i run "newgrp <group>" as root (e.g. running a script with newgrp in it using sudo), it dump me into a root shell.

Comment: This is not what newgrp should be used for. What happens if you forget to use to use newgrp outside of the script? How will the script handle the new shell that newgrp creates. @mark40's answer is better.

Comment: Is this really considered an answer? It's a link.

Comment: Can't help upvoting because that's interesting information. I still think @mark4o's answer should be the correct one.

Answer (score 232):

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. You can change the default group for all files created in a particular
   directory by setting the setgid flag on the directory ([`chmod g+s <dir>`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html)).
   New files in the directory will then be created with the group of the
   directory (set using `chgrp <group> <dir>`).  This applies to any program
   that creates files in the directory.

   Note that this is automagically inherited for new subdirectories (as of
   Linux 3.10).  However, if subdirectories were already present, this change
   won't be applied to them.  Assuming that the subdirectories already have the correct
   group, the setgid flag can be added to them with:
   `find . -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;` (suggested by Maciej Krawczyk in the comments)
2. If the setgid flag is not set, then the default group will be set to the current
   group id of the creating process.  Although this can be set using the `newgrp`
   command, that creates a new shell that is difficult to use within a shell
   script.  If you want to execute a particular command (or set of commands)
   with the changed group, use the command [`sg <group> <command>`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sg.1.html).

   `sg` is not a POSIX standard command but is available on Linux.

Comment: Just a small note. If you try to run `chmod g+s _dir_` on a directory which has the group y, and you are running the command under user x, and user x isn't member of the group y it wont' work. You'll have to run it as root.

Comment: @LEDfan ah! Excellent tip/point! This last part (user must be member of the group for it to work) is the one reason why I've struggled with getting this to work in the past. Thanks!

Comment: Do not use chmod -R You will apply setgid on files which creates a security problem (executable files will always run as the group owner, regardless who runs it). Use this instead to apply it for directories only `find . -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;`