# How can I configure rsync to create target directory on remote server?

Tags: rsync

I would like to `rsync` from local computer to server. On a directory that does not exist, and I want `rsync` to create that directory on the server first.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

If you have more than the last leaf directory to be created, you can either run a separate `ssh ... mkdir -p` first, or use the `--rsync-path` trick as [explained here](http://www.schwertly.com/2013/07/forcing-rsync-to-create-a-remote-path-using-rsync-path/) :

```
rsync -a --rsync-path="mkdir -p /tmp/x/y/z/ && rsync" $source user@remote:/tmp/x/y/z/
```

Or use the `--relative` option as suggested by Tony. In that case, you only specify the root of the destination, which must exist, and not the directory structure of the source, which will be created:

```
rsync -a --relative /new/x/y/z/ user@remote:/pre_existing/dir/
```

This way, you will end up with /pre_existing/dir/new/x/y/z/

And if you want to have "y/z/" created, but not inside "new/x/", you can add `./` where you want `--relative`to begin:

```
rsync -a --relative /new/x/./y/z/ user@remote:/pre_existing/dir/
```

would create /pre_existing/dir/y/z/.

Comment: The server i'm accessing doesn't have `mkdir`, so i'm using the hack: ```--rsync-path="echo f > /public/.keep && rsync /public/.keep /public/newfolder/ && rsync" \``` it does create an extra file but you can remove later.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on newer rsync protocols, I get an error similar to following when using && or ; in --rsync-path **invalid characters in scp command!
here:&& /usr/bin/rsync**

Comment: @ghitesh did you try to escape the `&&` ?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez Yeah I did, but did not work. I am not able to find the link now, but some documentation said this is fixed, as I believe it could (and was) be exploited.

Comment: Thanks, this works. In my case I was running a local bash script on a remote server and within that running the ssh mkdir command which was executing, but then killing the rest of the script before running the rsync command. This allows the rest of the script to run without issues.

Comment: @mivk this will not solve my problem can you please see the question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369009/how-to-solve-the-error-of-the-rsync-error-error-in-ipc-code-code-14-at-pipe-c)

Comment: The thing that still puzzles me is that instead of `rsync -a --relative /new/x/./y/z/ user@remote:/pre_existing/dir/` the following one achieves the same effect: `rsync -a /new/x/y/z/ user@remote:/pre_existing/dir/y`. So no need for `--relative` or `--rsync_path`, y just gets created by rsync. Or does that work locally only, with no remote (that's what I tried)? Why?

Comment: this is what i tried `rsync  
--archive 
--remove-source-files 
--rsync-path='mkdir -p /node1/node3/ && rsync' 
/xx/node1/node3/file.txt 
/node1/node3/file.txt'  `  But throws error. `node1/node3/ ` path doesnt exist in destination. Am i missing anything?. I am copying in the same host. So `remote` is not used.

Comment: what a joke to 'hack' , make  flag dang

Comment: For also setting the group for created dirs, `sg` can help: `--rsync-path="sg group_name \"mkdir -m 775 -p $destination_dir\" && rsync"`. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322706

Answer (score 125):

From the `rsync` manual page (`man rsync`):

```
--mkpath                 create the destination's path component
```

`--mkpath` was added in rsync 3.2.3 (6 Aug 2020).

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me.

Comment: Note that this option was only added in version 3.2.3 (6 Aug 2020).

Comment: Better a decade late than never! This flag is a lifesaver, you don't have to do any weird hacking of the syntax using e.g. `--relative` with this flag, you can simply leave a trailing slash on both source and destination paths and all recursive files/folders will be automatically synced between them...

Comment: To install rsync 3.2.3, supporting `--mkpath`, on old systems (not recommended for production):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389729/install-latest-version-of-rsync-3-2-3-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Shocking this was missing for soooo long.

Comment: this one works better, should be the answer!

Answer (score 39):

Assuming you are using ssh to connect rsync, what about to send a ssh command before:

```
ssh user@server mkdir -p existingdir/newdir
```

if it already exists, nothing happens

Comment: ufk's request is for syntax that will cause "rsync to create [a missing target] directory on the server [&& copy the files]." Your response is valid in that it will create the missing target directory on the server ... but not with `rsync`, therefore, no answer.

Comment: This is not an option if `ssh` is not supported and `rsync` connects to the `rsync daemon` on the remote end.

Answer (score 23):

The `-R, --relative` option will do this.

For example: if you want to backup `/var/named/chroot` and create the same directory structure on the remote server then `-R` will do just that.

Comment: You can also specify only part of the path to be created by using `/./` in the source path. See man page for details.

Comment: Why upvote? The answer is wrong, `rsync` won't create directories automatically if target folders don't exist. Sigh.

Comment: I strongly suggest readers to check the manpage for `--relative`. It might not do what you think.

Comment: --relative sticks the full path, rather than the file, at the endpoint you provide on the server. Normally /tmp/foo/bar/file.c to remote:/tmp would produce remote:/tmp/file.c but with -R it creates /tmp/foo/bar/file.c Don't use this option unless you know what you are doing, you will get a really messy directory structure.

Comment: @Marki555 's comment is key to success. `--relative` in conjunction with `/./` is what most newbies will be looking for. `rsync -avz -e ssh --progress --relative ~/./Desktop/ TARGET_IP:~/` will copy the contents of the desktop to the target desktop. Don't know how differences in usernames might affect this.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei You can execute commands(eg. create directories) on the remote machine via `ssh` before `rsync`. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: @zeekvfu, Well, my use case is different from the question, I want a zshrc function (one liner) to back-up a file inside a non existing folder

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Maybe I'm not clear enough. `ssh user@host "mkdir -p /tmp/hello.world" && rsync -arvz file_name user@host:/tmp/hello.world`, something like that. SSH public key authentication is required.

Comment: @zeekvfu, as @Marki555 stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server#comment27641151_17907667 and according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496181/5783, since `rsync` 2.6.7, `--relative` will create missing directory components on the remote side if you use `.` to anchor the starting parent directory to create at the destination. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55231772/107158.

Answer (score 21):

this worked for me:

```
 rsync /dev/null node:existing-dir/new-dir/
```

I do get this message :

```
skipping non-regular file "null"
```

but I don't have to worry about having an empty directory hanging around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer kdubs. That worked great.
So, if I want to keep the files I'm syncing inside of the folder I'm pointing to as the source, then I just need to specify it, and it gets created.

ex: rsync -avph /mytest/ /otherfolder/mytest/

Then I get the output "created directory /otherfolder/mytest"

Comment: Don't forget the slash ('/') at the end of new-dir, otherwise it will create a non-directory file.

Comment: it only works with single level of new-dir, if u want /new-dir1/new-dir2/ it won't work

Comment: true, in that case run it twice, or thrice... 8- )

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can do it with one rsync command, but you can 'pre-create' the extra directory first like this:

```
rsync --recursive emptydir/ destination/newdir
```

where 'emptydir' is a local empty directory (which you might have to create as a temporary directory first).

It's a bit of a hack, but it works for me.

cheers

Chris

Comment: No need to use temporary folder. See `rsync /dev/null node:existing-dir/new-dir/` suggestion above.

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses bits of other answers, but hopefully it'll be a bit clearer as to the circumstances. You never specified what you were rsyncing - a single directory entry or multiple files.

So let's assume you are moving a source directory entry across, and not just moving the files contained in it.

Let's say you have a directory locally called `data/myappdata/` and you have a load of subdirectories underneath this.
You have `data/` on your target machine but no `data/myappdata/` - this is easy enough:

```
rsync -rvv /path/to/data/myappdata/ user@host:/remote/path/to/data/myappdata
```

You can even use a different name for the remote directory:

```
rsync -rvv --recursive /path/to/data/myappdata user@host:/remote/path/to/data/newdirname
```

If you're just moving some files and not moving the directory entry that contains them then you would do:

```
rsync -rvv /path/to/data/myappdata/*.txt user@host:/remote/path/to/data/myappdata/
```

and it will create the `myappdata` directory for you on the remote machine to place your files in. Again, the `data/` directory must exist on the remote machine.

Incidentally, my use of `-rvv` flag is to get doubly verbose output so it is clear about what it does, as well as the necessary recursive behaviour.

Just to show you what I get when using rsync (3.0.9 on Ubuntu 12.04)

```
$ rsync -rvv *.txt user@remote.machine:/tmp/newdir/
opening connection using: ssh -l user remote.machine rsync --server -vvre.iLsf . /tmp/newdir/
user@remote.machine's password:
sending incremental file list
created directory /tmp/newdir
delta-transmission enabled
bar.txt
foo.txt
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
```

Hope this clears this up a little bit.

Comment: This does not *exactly* work as expected.  I tried the first command `rsync -rvv /path/to/data/myappdata user@host:/remote/path/to/data/myappdata` but what it created on the target is /remote/path/to/data/myappdata/myappdata/

Comment: If I make a slight change to your first command and add a slash '/' after the source path, then it works...like so:  `rsync -rvv /path/to/data/myappdata/ user@host:/remote/path/to/data/myappdata`

Answer (score 2):

eg:

from: /xxx/a/b/c/d/e/1.html

to: user@remote:/pre_existing/dir/b/c/d/e/1.html

rsync:

cd /xxx/a/ && rsync -auvR b/c/d/e/ user@remote:/pre_existing/dir/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version or rsync that doesn't have 'mkpath', then --files-from can help. Suppose you need to create 'mysubdir' in the target directory

Create 'filelist.txt' to contain
mysubdir/dummy

```
mkdir -p source_dir/mysubdir/
touch source_dir/mysubdir/dummy
rsync --files-from='filelist.txt' source_dir target_dir
```

rsync will copy mysubdir/dummy to target_dir, creating mysubdir in the process. Tested with rsync 3.1.3 on Raspberry Pi OS (debian).

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync source.pdf user1@192.168.56.100:~/not-created/target.pdf
```

If the target file is fully specified, the directory `~/not-created` is not created.

```
rsync source.pdf user1@192.168.56.100:~/will-be-created/
```

But the target is specified with only a directory, the directory `~/will-be-created` is created. `/` must be followed to let rsync know `will-be-created` is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

use rsync twice~

1: tranfer a temp file, make sure remote relative directories has been created.

```
tempfile=/Users/temp/Dir0/Dir1/Dir2/temp.txt
# Dir0/Dir1/Dir2/ is directory that wanted.
rsync -aq /Users/temp/ rsync://remote
```

2: then you can specify the remote directory for transfer files/directory

```
tempfile|dir=/Users/XX/data|/Users/XX/data/
rsync -avc /Users/XX/data rsync://remote/Dir0/Dir1/Dir2
# Tips: [SRC] with/without '/' is different
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates the dir tree `/usr/local/bin` in the destination and then syncs all containing files and folders recursively:

```
rsync --archive --include="/usr" --include="/usr/local" --include="/usr/local/bin" --include="/usr/local/bin/**" --exclude="*" user@remote:/ /home/user
```

Compared to `mkdir -p`, the dir tree even has the same perms as the source.

Answer (score 0):

Did not find it said clearly here, but recent `rsync` (version 3.2.7) simply creates those directories by default.

`rsync -zvh backup.tar.gz /tmp/backups/`

output:

```
created directory /tmp/backups
backup.tar.gz

sent 224.54K bytes  received 70 bytes  449.21K bytes/sec
total size is 224.40K  speedup is 1.00
```