# How do I rsync a file to a remote directory that doesn't exist?

Tags: rsync

Suppose I want to rsync file `foo.txt` on my local machine to file `/home/me/somedirectory/bar.txt` on a remote computer, and that `somedirectory/` doesn't yet exist. How do I do this?

I tried `rsync -e ssh -z foo.txt remotemachine:/home/me/somedirectory/bar.txt`, but I get a `rsync: push_dir#3 "/home/me/somedirectory" failed: No such file or directory (2)` error.

(Copying the file without renaming it works, though. That is, this runs fine: rsync -e ssh -z foo.txt remotemachine:/home/me/somedirectory/`)

Comment: I think you can find the same question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server).

Comment: I tried adding the `--recursive` flag, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Just put a trailing slash on your target dir.  Something like this:

rsync foo.txt remotemachine:somedirectory/

Assuming that "/home/me" is your home dir on the remote machine, there is no need to specify it in the command line.  Also, you don't need to clutter up your rsync with the -e unless you just like to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this process successfully in 2 stepes:-

1]  `rsync -e ssh -z foo.txt remotemachine:/home/me/somedirectory/`
this will copy the foo.txt and create directory `somedirectory` on destination.

then

2]  `rsync -e ssh -z --delete-after foo.txt remotemachine:/home/me/somedirectory/bar.txt`

and here you can delete foo.txt on destination by using `--delete-after`  option.
you can see it's usage from man pages. This option must be used with -r option
This serves your purpose.

or if second command doesn't work then use :-
`rsync -e ssh -z foo.txt remotemachine:/home/me/somedirectory/bar.txt` 
and delete  foo.txt manually.