# How to force rsync to create destination folder

Tags: rsync

Example:

```
rsync /tmp/fol1/fol2/fol3/foln user@addr:/tmp/fol1/fol2/fol3/foln
```

My main problem is folder /tmp/fol1 doesn't exist on remote machine.

Which arguments can I use to force rsync to create this tree?

Comment: Same question here: [rsync: how can I configure it to create target directory on server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server)

Answer (score 30):

I ran into same issue today and found the solution [here](http://markmail.org/message/4z4o2huvxrw2auz6).

You can either do:

```
rsync -avR foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
```

or:

```
rsync -avR somedir/./foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
```

to create /tmp/foo/bar/baz.c in the remote machine.

see `--relative/-R` section of `man rsync` for more details.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. But it does not work with the Cygwin port of rsync :(

Comment: this doesn't work if your source and destination paths aren't the same

Comment: what if i want to copy to root directory like this?  ` rsync -avR somedir/./foo/bar/baz.c .` to copy from `/somedir/foo/bar/baz.c`  to `/foo/bar/baz.c`.  I couldnt make it work. Im not copying to remote.

Answer (score 23):

One trick to do it is to use the `--rsync-path` parameter with the following value:

```
--rsync-path="mkdir -p /tmp/fol1 && rsync"
```

With --rsync-path you can specify what program is going to be used to start rsync in the remote machine and is run with the help of a shell.

Answer (score 2):

rysnc version 3.2.3 (6 Aug 2020) [added the `--mkpath` option](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.2.3) which achieves this purpose.

`man rsync` documents:

```
--mkpath                 create the destination's path component
```

Ubuntu 22.04 is the first Ubuntu version that will get this option as per: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rsync&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all

This had been previously mentioned in another answer to this question which got deleted, also mentioned at: [rsync - create all missing parent directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491548/rsync-create-all-missing-parent-directories/72178224#72178224)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via bash and open a ssh tunnel make the file structure you need to make then rsync the data. Will these temp folders change each time this sync is done? eg is it for each day of the week?

```
ssh user@address
mkdir -p tmp/fol1
rsync avz /tmp/fol1/fol2/fol3/foln user@addr:/tmp/fol1/fol2/fol3/foln
fi
```