# rsync - create all missing parent directories?

Tags: rsync, scp

I'm looking for an `rsync`-like program which will create any missing parent directories on the remote side.

For example, if I have `/top/a/b/c/d` on one server and only `/top/a` exists on the remote server, I want to copy `d` to the remote server and have the `b` and `c` directories created as well.

The command:

```
rsync /top/a/b/c/d remote:/top/a/b/c
```

won't work because `/tmp/a/b` doesn't exist on the remote server. And if it did exist then the file `d` would get copied to the path `/top/a/b/c`.

This is possible to do with `rsync` using `--include` and `--exclude` switches, but it is very involved, e.g.:

```
rsync -v -r a dest:dir  \
  --include 'a/b'       \
  --include 'a/b/c'     \
  --include 'a/b/c/d'   \
  --include 'a/b/c/d/e' \
  --exclude 'a/*'       \
  --exclude 'a/b/*'     \
  --exclude 'a/b/c/*'   \
  --exclude 'a/b/c/d/*'
```

will only copy `a/b/c/d/e` to `dest:dir/a/b/c/d/e` even if the intermediate directories have files. (Note - the includes must precede the excludes.)

Are there any other options?

Comment: See also [rsync: how can I configure it to create target directory on server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force rsync to create destination folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242135/how-to-force-rsync-to-create-destination-folder)

Answer (score 31):

You may be looking for

```
rsync -aR
```

for example:

```
rsync -a --relative /top/a/b/c/d remote:/
```

See also this trick in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22908437/111036).

Comment: Why include `-a` too? I'm pretty sure it's not needed.

Comment: @KennyEvitt `-a` uses recursive (`-r`) but not relative (`-R`) so `-a` is still needed sometimes to preserve owner/perms (`-aR`). You can test it running rsync as root (or another user) to see this behavior.

Comment: `--relative` will not _create_ missing directory components on the remote side like in the question.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, complains `rsync: mkdir "/home/constantine/Projects/schifra-pkg/pkg/schifra-git/usr/include/schifra" failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: @juzzlin, according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496181/5783, since `rsync` 2.6.7, `--relative` will create missing directory components on the remote side if you use `.` to anchor the starting parent directory to create at the destination. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55231772/107158.

Comment: @DerekMahar  Great instructions.  I have followed yours and was able to get missing directories created and copy worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 25):

As of [version 3.2.3](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.2.3) (6 Aug 2020), `rynsc` has a flag for this purpose.

From the `rsync` manual page (`man rsync`):

```
--mkpath                 create the destination's path component
```

Answer (score 19):

```
rsync -aq --rsync-path='mkdir -p /tmp/imaginary/ && rsync' file user@remote:/tmp/imaginary/
```

From http://www.schwertly.com/2013/07/forcing-rsync-to-create-a-remote-path-using-rsync-path/, but don't copy and paste from there, his syntax is butchered.

it lets you execute arbitrary command to setup the path for rsync executables.

Comment: Very nice, this is preferable because it doesn't require a separate ssh connection. Forgot the `&& rsync` and was getting cryptic error messages.

Comment: this is what i tried `rsync  
--archive 
--remove-source-files 
--rsync-path='mkdir -p /node1/node3/ && rsync' 
/xx/node1/node3/file.txt 
/node1/node3/file.txt'  `  But throws error. `node1/node3/ ` path doesnt exist in destination. Am i missing anything?. I am copying in the same host. So `remote` is not used.

Comment: This is the only answer that works with absolute paths and old versions of rsync, including the version of rsync that ships with macOS Sonoma 14 in 2024.

Answer (score 10):

i suggest that you enforce the existence manually:

```
ssh user@remote mkdir -p /top/a/b/c
rsync /top/a/b/c/d remote:/top/a/b/c
```

this creates the target folder if it does not exists already.

Comment: Yes - that is one way to do it. But it seems that my use case is such a useful scenario that there should be a command for it or some options to rsync.

Comment: i am not aware of any such flag.

Answer (score 7):

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496181/5783, since rsync 2.6.7, `--relative` works if you use `.` to anchor the starting parent directory to create at the destination:

```
derek@DESKTOP-2F2F59O:~/projects/rsync$ mkdir --parents top1/a/b/c/d
derek@DESKTOP-2F2F59O:~/projects/rsync$ mkdir --parents top2/a
derek@DESKTOP-2F2F59O:~/projects/rsync$ rsync --recursive --relative --verbose top1/a/./b/c/d top2/a/
sending incremental file list
b/
b/c/
b/c/d/

sent 99 bytes  received 28 bytes  254.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173623/107158 describes the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

`--relative` does not work for me since I had different setup.
Maybe I just didn't understood how `--relative` works, but I found that the

```
ssh remote mkdir -p /top/a/b/c
rsync /top/a/b/c/d remote:/top/a/b/c
```

is easy to understand and does the job.

Comment: `--relative` didn't work for you, because it has nothing to do with this :)

Comment: @juzzlin Maybe I just didn't understood how  --relative works. ;)

Comment: @juzzlin, according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496181/5783, since rsync 2.6.7, `--relative` works if you use `.` to anchor the starting parent directory to create at the destination.  See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55231772/107158.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a better solution, but mine seems to be better suited when you have too many sub-directories to create them manually.

Simply use `cp` as an intermediate step with the `--parents` option

```
cp --parents /your/path/sub/dir/ /tmp/localcopy
rsync [options] /tmp/localcopy/* remote:/destination/path/
```

`cp --parents` will create the structure for you.

You can call it from any subfolder if you want only one subset of the parent folders to be copied.

Comment: `cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory`

Answer (score 2):

A shorter way in Linux to create rsync destination paths is to use the '$_' Special Variable. (I think, but cannot confirm, that it is also the same in OSX).

'$_' holds the value of the last argument of the previous command executed. So the question could be answered with:

`ssh remote mkdir -p /top/a/b/c/ && rsync -avz /top/a/b/c/d remote:$_`

Comment: I didn't like this solution at first but it looks like it's the best choice for my situation where I'm trying to create directories that don't exist in the source hierarchy.