# Cannot get rsync to accept `mkdir -p` (--parents) in rsync-path argument?

Tags: shell, rsync

I've seen in posts like [rsync - create all missing parent directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491548/rsync-create-all-missing-parent-directories) :

```
rsync -aq --rsync-path='mkdir -p /tmp/imaginary/ && rsync' file user@remote:/tmp/imaginary/
```

I thought - great, let me try that:

```
$ rsync -aP --remove-source-files --rsync-path="mkdir -p /home/pi/ARCHIVE/2020/01/24 && rsync" a1.test a1.json a1.pdf /home/pi/ARCHIVE/2020/01/24/
sending incremental file list
rsync: mkdir "/home/pi/ARCHIVE/2020/01/24" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(675) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Well, sure `mkdir "/home/pi/ARCHIVE/2020/01/24" failed` - but I did NOT issue `mkdir`, i issued `mkdir -p`!

So why did rsync ignore this? Is there any other setting I should set for it? Or maybe rsync-path can be used STRICTLY for ssh connections (which is not the case here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--rsync-path` only applies to remote machines:

```
--rsync-path=PROGRAM    specify the rsync to run on remote machine
```

This is because you don't need to invoke a second instance of `rsync` when you are doing a local copy. The copy will simply be done by the process you ran.

Since it's technically *you* who are invoking rsync on the target machine, it's *you* who should be adding `mkdir .. &&` in front of `rsync`:

```
mkdir -p /home/pi/ARCHIVE/2020/01/24 &&
    rsync -aP --remove-source-files a1.test a1.json a1.pdf /home/pi/ARCHIVE/2020/01/24/
```