# Why rsync uses mkdir without p option

Tags: rsync, mkdir

As I can see `rsync` can't sync file if some of directories in file path doesn't exist. Why it doesn't create this directories with `mkdir -p` command? Maybe it has an option for that? `-r` option doesn't work in that case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Somebody asked a similar question here:

[rsync: how can I configure it to create target directory on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/)

It doesn't look like `rsync` is able to do that. You would have to write a wrapper script that does a `mkdir -p` on the target directory before executing `rsync`. If your target directory is on a different server, you might be able to run the `mkdir -p` command in a script through `ssh`.

Comment: The question you linked to now has an accepted answer which explains that the `--relative` option does make rsync create the needed directories.

Comment: even with the switch `--rsync-path="mkdir -p /dir && rsync" ` it will not create a dir. I wrote a shell script and create new /dir right before rsync command is issued. It works like this.

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered the same problem same as you, if the directory of remote target is "`/root/test`" and I want to use `rsync` to replicate my files to the remote directory "`/root/test/aaa/bbb`", then "`failed: No such file or directory (2)`" will verbose out.
The best solution is, give the command "`ssh <username>@<remoteHostIP> mkdir -p <absolute_path>`" for recursively create the sub-directories at the remote host. Then use `rsync`   command will success.

Comment: In the end I do the same. Looks like there is no convenient way to persuade rsync create directories recursively