# Ansible synchronise fails if parent directories are not already created

Tags: ansible

I have a synchronisation task in ansible:

```
---
- name: Copy over code - lib
  synchronize:
    src: ../lib/some/parent/directories/
    dest: ~/project/lib/some/parent/directories/
```

This fails as the destination lacks `~/project/lib/some/parent/` but succeeds otherwise.  I produced the following work around:

```
---
- set_fact:
    directory_lib_dest: ~/project/lib/some/parent/directories/
- name: Create directories
  file: path={{ item }} state=directory
  with_items:
    - "{{ directory_lib_dest }}"
- name: Copy over code - lib
  synchronize:
    src: ../lib/some/parent/directories/
    dest: "{{ directory_lib_dest }}"
```

Is there a better solution that can be done using soley the [ansible synchronize module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) and or avoids me using `set_fact` whilst keeping it DRY and the variable declared in the same role .yml that is consuming it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much to Konstantin's answer, I ended up using:

```
---
- name: Set name of local and remote project directory
  set_fact:
    LOCAL_PROJECT_DIRECTORY:  "{{ playbook_dir | dirname }}"
    REMOTE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/project-remote-dir/"
- name: Create remote project directory {{ REMOTE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY }}
  file: path={{ REMOTE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY }} state=directory
- name: Copy over code
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ LOCAL_PROJECT_DIRECTORY }}/./{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ REMOTE_PROJECT_DIRECTORY }}"
    rsync_opts:
      - "--relative"
  with_items:
    - lib/some/parent/directories/
    - src/some/other/directories/
```

The `LOCAL_PROJECT_DIRECTORY` took the `dirname` of the `playbook_dir` as the project is structured like:

```
myproject
    deploy
        playbook.yml
        roles
             etc...
    lib
        etc...
    src
        etc...
```

This is doubly nice as it's removed repetition of the `some/parent/directories` and made everything much more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

This is how `rsync` works. But you can read about workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server).

If you going to adopt `relative` behaviour with *dot-slash* trick, keep in mind that you should pass full path to `src` in Ansible (otherwise Ansible will expand it on its own and your `/./` trick will be eliminated).

If you need to recreate `lib/some/parent/directories/` your task may look like this:

**TEST IT BEFORE REAL USE!**

```
- synchronize:
    src: '{{ playbook_dir }}/./lib/some/parent/directories/'
    dest: ~/project/
    rsync_opts: 
      - '--relative'
```

As I said `src: .././lib/some/parent/dir` will not work, we need full path (so I used `playbook_dir` magic variable).

Excerpt from `rsync` man page about `relative`:

> To limit the amount of path information that is sent, you have a couple options:  (1)  With
>                 a  modern  rsync  on the sending side (beginning with 2.6.7), you can insert a dot and a slash into the
>                 source path, like this: `rsync -avR /foo/./bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/`

Comment: Hey @Konstantin, if you'd like to copy my answer into yours I'll mark yours as correct and delete mine and this comment, up to you.  Thanks very much for your answer!  It really helped.

Comment: @AJP, thanks, but I'd rather not. I'd like to keep my answer text intact.