# rsync create absent leaf directory

Tags: bash, rsync

I want to make a rsync with an update of the distant tree. I'd like my command to recursively create missings leaf folders ex :

Before:
Source
A/A/C_file
A/B/C_file
A/C/C_file
B/A/C_file
B/B/C_file
B/C/C_file

distant
A/A/C_file
A/C/C_file
B/A/C_file
B/C/C_file

After the Rsync command "rsync -atvrz source/dir/ distant/dir " : 
Distant : 
A/A/C_file
A/B/C_file
A/C/C_file
B/A/C_file
B/B/C_file
B/C/C_file
[The --relative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server) doesn't work for me because it creates the new path inside the distant : "distant/dir/source/dir"

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work when the user right is harmonized. 
So a `chown -r user:user /distant` solved the issue.