# rsync command is giving error No such file or directory (2)

Tags: unix, rsync

I am trying to transfer  a file using in remote desktop which will create the directory tree as well in remote desktop as specified.I am using below command but its not working when directory is not present in remote server.

```
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress /root/BP/temp/temp.txt root@host2:/root/BP/temp2
```

Where `/root/BP/temp/temp.txt` is available in local but `/root/BP/temp2` this path is not peresent in remote server.

I am getting below error :

```
rsync: change_dir#3 "/root/BP" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(625) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Answer (score 1):

If one has to create manually the remote dir tree before using rsync, it gets less useful, right? So let's look for alternatives.

First, let's clarify that OP's command

```
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress /root/BP/temp/temp.txt root@host2:/root/BP/temp2
```

would create the **file** /root/BP/temp2 at receiver `host2`. (If he wanted /root/BP/temp2 **/temp.txt**, then he should have added / at the end of the destination path)

In principle, rsync will only create **one** destination folder. So the OP's command would work if the receiver had an existing path /root/: dir BP is the new folder that gets created, and inside of it file temp2 gets created.

If using rsync -r (recursive), a tree is created in the destination **while** the source is copied. But in this case it doesn't help because the source is a file!

Since 2020 (rsync 3.2.3) there's a --mkpath option that addresses the problem directly.

And before that, there's an ugly hack that can help to create the intermediate directories. ... See [How can I configure rsync to create target directory on remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/how-can-i-configure-rsync-to-create-target-directory-on-remote-server) . But for that, I find it easier to just do
`ssh root@host2 mkdir -p /root/BP`.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to move files to a non existent path on the remote server, you must either:

1. Model the path and file structure locally and sync a common "ancestor".

   - This is requires only 1 step
2. Create the missing directories locally and sync them first then sync the files.

   - This requires 2 steps

To use the OP's specific example of:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress /root/BP/temp/temp.txt root@host2:/root/BP/temp2
```

You would instead do:

```
# assuming that /root already exists on the remote server
mkdir -p /root/BP/temp/or_wherever/BP/temp2
mv /root/BP/temp/temp.txt /root/BP/temp/or_wherever/BP/temp2
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress /root/BP/temp/or_wherever/BP root@host2:/root/
```

But if for some reason you cannot move the file in question, you must use the second option:

```
# assuming that /root already exists on the remote server
mkdir -p /root/BP/temp/or_wherever/BP/temp2
# Notice there is no `/` after the       `or_wherever/BP` in the next command
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress /root/BP/temp/or_wherever/BP root@host2:/root/
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress /root/BP/temp/temp.txt root@host2:/root/BP/temp2/
```

Comment: It seems this will copy the whole folder `BP`. What if there are other files in there, but you only want to move `temp.txt` and its directory ancestors?

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 I really don't see a 3rd option. Yes, `rsync` will sync "other files". So, you either: (Option 1 above) Create a directory & file structure locally that you are willing to sync. Or, (Option 2 above) Create an empty directory structure, sync it, then sync the file(s) into their exact locations now that the locations have been created.

Comment: Having to create manually the remote dir tree before using rsync makes it not very useful, right? there are usually better ways!