# How to solve the error of the rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.2]

Tags: ubuntu, go, rsync, mkdir

I'm using a command of rsync for making a new directory to save the images the command is `"rsync -ave --rsync-path='mkdir -p " + path + " && rsync' " + filePath + " ubuntu@" + LocalhostIp + ":" + path` but while running my code this command will gives me the error the error is

Error:

> exit status 14: rsync: Failed to exec --rsync-path=mkdir: No such file or directory (2)
>
> rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.2]
>
> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
>
> rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]

**Edit**

```
func CopyUploadedFileToAppServers(filePath, path string) {
   ExecuteCommand("rsync -ave --rsync-path='mkdir -p " + path + " && rsync' " + filePath + " ubuntu@" + LocalhostIp + ":" + path)
}

func ExecuteCommand(command string) error{
 cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c",command)
 var out bytes.Buffer
 var stderr bytes.Buffer
 cmd.Stdout = &out
 cmd.Stderr = &stderr

 err := cmd.Run()

 if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    return err
 }
 fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
 return nil
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: In ExecuteCommand func replace ```cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c",command)``` with

```cm := []string{"-c"} cm = append(cm, strings.Split(command, " ")...)   cmd := exec.Command("sh", cm...)```

Comment: @hoque the solution you tell I applied it into my code and run but It gives me error of `exit status 1: rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/`

Comment: Can you ensure your ```rsync -ave --rsync-path='mkdir -p " + path + " && rsync' " + filePath + " ubuntu@" + LocalhostIp + ":" + path``` command work from your pc? And also it will be easy to me if you give the value of the variable, so that i can check.

Comment: @hoque I run this `rsync -ave --rsync-path="mkdir -p /var/www/html/uploads/ironnetwork/ && rsync" /var/www/html/uploads/ironnetwork/1542607804image.` command directly in the terminal and it will give me the error `sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/var/www/html/uploads/ironnetwork" failed: No such file or directory (2)
` Now Can you solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `-e` option, as this is taking the following work (`--rsync-path=...`) as the replacement for the ssh command. For example,

```
$ rsync -ave --x_x  /tmp/a abc@localhost:/tmp/y
rsync: Failed to exec --x_x: No such file or directory (2)
```

Just use `-av`.

Comment: As you say @meuh I remove the flag `-e` and then I run the command then it will give me the error `exit status 1: rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.`

Comment: exit 1 is a syntax error in the arguments. Perhaps your `path` or `filePath` strings have characters that are being interpreted by the shell. Try adding `-x` 
in your ExecuteCommand, (`cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-xc",command)`)  to see what is actually being passed to rsync.

Comment: now it will print this `exit status 1: + rsync 
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31`

Comment: I don't know the *go* language, so I cannot help you with this. You are not getting the entire error message. Perhaps you introduced a typing error when you converted the `-ave` to `-av`.

Comment: Can you tell me how I run this command successfully on ubuntu terminal? @meuh

Comment: I presume you should be typing a command like: `rsync -av --rsync-path="mkdir -p /var/www/html/uploads/ironnetwork/ && rsync" /var/www/html/uploads/ironnetwork/1542607804image ubuntu@remotehost:/var/www/html/uploads/ironnetwork/`

Comment: it was asking for the password what should I write there?

Comment: This has gone too far away from the original question. I suggest you look back at what you are trying to achieve, simplify it, and start a new question, referring back to this one if appropriate.

Comment: actually I told  you what I gona achieve is that I want to write an image from the live [this](https://loctest.bookingkoala.co.in/uploads/loctest/2018/11/17/1542430701aaa.jpg) image into my desktop using rsync command. Can you help me to do this?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372121/how-to-write-a-image-from-the-live-url-into-local-system-using-rsync) question