# How to write a image from the live url into local system using rsync

Tags: image, terminal, rsync

I want to save a image or load a image which is on this example [image link](https://loctest.bookingkoala.co.in/uploads/loctest/2018/11/17/1542430701aaa.jpg) into my computer using rsync command into the terminal. Can anybody tell me how to save the image using terminal command? Path is:- `/home/iron/go/src/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm adding my answer to load a image from server to the local system or you can say remote machine to local machine

Here is the little code

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "io"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  url := "https://www.bookingkoala.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cropped-logo.png" // your url
  // don't worry about errors
  response, e := http.Get(url) // getting data from the url
  if e != nil || response == nil {
    return
  }
  defer response.Body.Close()

  //open a file for writing
  file, err := os.Create("/home/iron/go/src/abc/sada.png") // define path and file name where you want to store the image.
  if err != nil || response == nil {
    // log.Fatal(err)
    return
  }
  defer file.Close()

  // Use io.Copy to just dump the response body to the file. This supports huge files
  _, err = io.Copy(file, response.Body) // it will make or copy a file of the image in the link
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Println("Success!")
}
```

I think it satisfied your question.