# Rsync file automatically creating directory

Tags: bash, sh, rsync, file-transfer, scp

I'm a beginner with rsync.
I have a file "filelist.txt" with some files with full path :

```
/tmp/folder1/file.txt
/tmp/folder2/file.txt
/tmp/folder2/file.txt
```

I want to copy this files from the server A to serveur B, and create directories if it's needed.
This file can evolve several time a day, so I don't want to handle dir creation manually on the other server before transfert files.

So I used :

```
cat filelist.txt | xargs -I {} rsync -r {} admin@ttt.i-test.fr:{}
```

But I have for each line :

```
rsync: change_dir#3 "/tmp/folder1" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(632) [receiver=3.0.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22908437/3776858

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--relative` option. For example:

```
rsync --files-from filelist.txt -R -av / user@host:/
```

---

According to [rsync manual](https://man.cx/rsync):

> - -R, --relative
>
>   Use  relative  paths. This means that **the full path names specified on the command line are sent to the server** rather than just the last parts of the filenames. This is **particularly useful when you  want  to send several different directories** at the same time. For example, if you used this command:
>
>   ```
>       rsync -av /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
>   ```
>
>   ... this would create a file named `baz.c` in `/tmp/` on the remote machine. If instead you used
>
>   ```
>       rsync -avR /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
>   ```
>
>   then  a file named `/tmp/foo/bar/baz.c` would be created on the remote machine, preserving its full path. These extra path elements are called "implied directories" (i.e. the `"foo"` and the  `"foo/bar"`  directories in the above example).
>
>   [...]

Comment: It works, but I still had some weird error : building file list ... done
cannot delete non-empty directory: tmp
could not make way for new symlink: tmp
tmp/folder2/
tmp/folder2/file.txt
tmp/folder2/toto.sh

sent 254 bytes  received 70 bytes  129.60 bytes/sec
total size is 26  speedup is 0.08
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/d7e177bcf5/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]

Comment: only limited formatting is allowed in comments. it's not good for discussion. please ask a new question.