# set default owner for new file in fedora

Tags: linux, default, fedora, file-ownership

My system will auto create an image file for captcha. I want the captcha to have a default owner of "my_username apache" when it was created. 
currently it was created with owner such as this "apache apache"

I am using Fedora.

Kindly tell me what is the linux command for that.
Thanks

Comment: probably duplicate ,go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321168/bash-scripting-how-to-set-the-group-that-new-files-will-be-created-with

Answer (score -1):

`sudo chown apache:apache chaptcha_file`

For default permissions for owner check `umask` here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html