# How to change the group owner of a file that gets created by a script

Tags: linux, redhat

I'm trying to change the group owner of an output file that gets created from a script.  right now the output looks like this :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oasedms dba  1898 Apr 10 15:42 DRAFT_342870_8_1.xml
```

I want the group owner to be "adlib-adm" instead of dba.

I'm running this on rhel 6.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like always? Google "file change group linux"?

Comment: `sudo chown adlib-adm:adlib-adm DRAFT_342870_8_1.xml` will change the group ownership as well as user ownership of the file...

Comment: i know i can change it individually but i want the default group to be adlib-adm when the script gets executed.  So when the script gets executed I want all the files to have adlib-adm ad the group owner.  I already changed the group owner of the directory

Comment: Ah. You may want to edit your question.-- Presumably the default group of a file created by a script is that of the "primary" group of that user which can be set via `usermod`. (I have never done that, just googled...). Of course changing the primary group will have side effects which may be unintended, in which case changing the group explicitly is the only recourse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash Scripting - How to set the group that new files will be created with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321168/bash-scripting-how-to-set-the-group-that-new-files-will-be-created-with)

Comment: This really belongs on the ServerFault.  But even more problematic is this is found through any basic google search.

Answer (score 2):

you can use chown command to change the owner and goup of the file.

```
chown adlib-adm:group /address/of/file
```

I hope this helps. Have a good day.

Comment: Very exact and helpful !

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I do know that you can change the group owner of individual files like that but what i want is that there is a script thats being executed and when it gets executed the files that it creates should AUTOMATICALLY have adlib-adm as a group owner.

Comment: you should simply add these lines at the end of the bash script or you may  call a bash script from the program before it ends. the bash script will change the permissions

Comment: I do understand that and I have recommended that to the end user but theres another server that has the same exact script and everything and when tht script gets run in that server the output has the correct group owner.  The end user wants to know why its right on one server and not on the other eventhough they are the same exact servers.  The script thats running successfully is the prod server and the other one is dev.

Comment: have you checked the group of  the user who is creating the file over the server where the correct file is getting generated. if the user is present in the required group then you can access that file

Comment: all the users and groups are actually in Active directory and controlled by VAS

Answer (score 0):

```
chgrp adlib-adm DRAFT_342870_8_1.xml
```

**Edit:** See [Bash Scripting - How to set the group that new files will be created with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321168/bash-scripting-how-to-set-the-group-that-new-files-will-be-created-with)

You may also want to consider [sg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/sg.1.html) :

`sg [-] [group [-c ] command]`

> sg - execute command as different group ID.  The sg command works similar to newgrp but accepts a command. The
>          command will be executed with the /bin/sh shell.

Comment: I actually want it to change automatically when the script gets executed.